# Is the pronoun “it” in the correct position?

Tags: sentence-construction, pronouns

> The book that your father got from USA yesterday I want **it** for few days to read.

The pronoun used “it” which refer to book - is it in correct position?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply write the sentence as - 
**I want the book that your father got from USA for a few days to read.**
This eliminates the need to insert a pronoun in the above sentence.

However, if you insist on writing it as two separate sentences, it can be done in the following way -
*Your father brought a book from USA yesterday. I want it for a few days to read.*
In this case it will be understood that the pronoun 'it' has appeared for the book. And yes, its position in the sentence is also correct.

Comment: It would be a little more polite to say “I would like it” instead of “I want it” if you are requesting to borrow it. In this context, “want” can be interpreted as a demand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this word order, but only in informal spoken English. If you write it down as reported speech, you have to separate the two parts:

> The book that your father got from the USA yesterday -- I want it for few
>   days to read.

There is a significant pause between 'yesterday' and 'I'.